# Задержка при нажатии на клавишу

Tags: jquery, javascript, клавиатура

Здравствуйте, такая проблема:
Нужно, чтобы при удерживании клавиши "Вверх" div двигался вверх. Все работает, однако при нажатии и удерживании div двигается на 1%, а затем замирает на долю секунды и снова движется.
Это происходит, как и при перемещении мигающего курсора при написании сообщения.

Код:

```
up=50;
    lt=50;
    $(document).keydown(function(event){
    if (event.keyCode == 38) {
    up=up-1;
    document.getElementById('player').style.top=up+'%';
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 40) {
    up=up+1;
    document.getElementById('player').style.top=up+'%';
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 37) {
    lt=lt-1;
    document.getElementById('player').style.left=lt+'%';
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 39) {
    lt=lt+1;
    document.getElementById('player').style.left=lt+'%';
    }
    });
```

Comment: @Urushigo, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 1):

```
var timerUp;
var up = 50;

$(document).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 38 && timer == null){
    timerUp = setInterval(function(){
        $('#player').css('top',(up--)+'%');
    },300);
}
$(document).keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 38 && timer != null){
    clearInterval(timerUp);
}
```

Для вниз, влево, вправо аналогично. Мог что-то напутать, но в целом идея такая.